# accessing imageview inside cardview as recyclerview item with espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

to catch an ImageView with espresso directly, you simply use

```
 onView(withId(R.id.imageviewid)
```

now I have a RecyclerView with a list of CardViews each containing an ImageView. how you can achieve to hold one of these ImageViews in your hand like in the simple direct way? they all have the same Id. only difference between the CardViews actually is an ImageView sibling TextView with different text

Comment: Can you share your code?